# How to get data from specific row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I am still new to python and I need help.

I have several csv files. One of them look like this:

*test.csv*

```
Name,Colour,ID
Fiona,Brown,23
Alex,Brown,24
Mary,Pink,25
Jane,Yellow,26
John,Pink,27
Emma,Yellow,28
```

And another file looks like this:

*test2.csv*

```
Name,Colour,ID
Gwen,Black,29
Peter,Brown,30
Stranger,Black,31
Abou,Yellow,32
Jonah,Yello,33
Kim,Yellow,34
```

I'm trying to check if a certain colour exist in the file and extract its row.

Here is what i've tried.

```html
import pandas as pd

#User input file name
filename = input("Enter file name: ")


#Open and read CSV file
file = pd.read_csv(filename + ".csv")

#Check if black exist or not
if 'Black' in file:
    bl = file.loc["Black"]
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No Black")


if 'Brown' in file:
    Brown = file.loc["Brown"]
    print(Brown)
else:
    print("No brown")


if 'Pink' in file:
    Pink = file.loc["Pink"]
    print(Pink)
else:
    print("No Pink")


if 'Yellow' in file:
    Yellow = file.loc["Yellow"]
    print(Yellow)
else:
    print("No Yellow")
```

This is the output that I get when I run my code

```
Enter file name: test
No Black
No brown
No Pink
No Yellow
```

Is there any suggestion so that I can get the output correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` is a dataframe.  If you do `if 'Black' in file` it will only search the column names (which are `['Name', 'Colour', 'ID']`).

You need to be more specific about where you want to search (i.e. which column to search).

To find `'black'` in the colour column use:

```
if 'black' in file['Colour'].values:
    bl = file.loc[file['Colour'] == "Black"]
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert this column (Series) to list if you want to use `in` statement:

```
COLORS = ['Black', 'Brown', 'Pink', 'Yellow']

filename = input('Enter file name: ')
df = pd.read_csv(f'{filename}.csv')


colors = df['Colour'].tolist()

for color in COLORS:
    print(f'{color}' if color in colors else f'no {color}')
```

Output:

```
Enter file name: test
no Black
Brown
Pink
Yellow
```